# create react app works but gives no starter code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I think I must have messed something up on my computer, but I'm not sure what. I did

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

everything works fine but I don't get and starter code. All I'm getting is the node modules and the package.json

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  }
}
```

anyone know how to reset it all so it gives me the starter code again?

[image]

Comment: can you try npm instead of npx

Comment: If you still have a global install of `create-react-app` this may be the problem.  If so, I would suggest running `npm un -g create-react-app` and then trying to run `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: npm un -g create-react-app and doing it again and it didn't work. I'm pretty perplexed here.